# Cannot covert value of type string to [string] in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of data I parsed to `csvRows`. Now I want each [3] object to append to a new array. However I get an error saying "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[String]'"

```
class Club {
    var Club: [[String]] = []
    var ClubName: String = ""
    var MP: Int?
    var W: Int?
    var D: Int?
    var L: Int?
    var GF: Int?
    var GA: Int?
    var GD: Int?
    var PTS: Int?
    var Last5: String?
    
    func addClub(){
        var data = readDataFromURL(url: "https://fixturedownload.com/download/epl-2020-GMTStandardTime.csv")
        var csvRows = csv(data: data!)
        for rows in csvRows {
            var teamName = rows[3]
            print(teamName)
            Club.append(teamName)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really enough information here to be sure what your intent is, but I think the most likely solution is to change the definition of `var Club` to be:

```swift
var Club: [String] = []
```

This would make `Club` an array of strings, so it could hold information like
`["Fuham", "Burnley", "Man City"]`.

As you currently have it written it is an array of arrays of strings.

---

If you a really wanted an array of arrays of strings you could change the assignment to be:

```swift
Club.append([teamName])
```

but without more context it's hard to see why that would make sense.